# Passing from django formset to

Tags: json, django

This is my first Django project and this little bit turned out to be quite hard. I am making an itinerary generator by using formsets. These can be duplicated (I already know at least how to do it by working out the management form and all). For every event (it's someone traveling) I have passed information about the starting date and ending date, which is displayed on the form like this: Date 1 [Form 1][Form 2], Date 2 [Form 3][Form 4]. My problem is that in the end, when I put it back into the view, I would like to use `json.dumps` to turn it into an array, with the idea that the code is more readable and usable. Something like this:

```
{
"28-June-2017": 
    [
        {"time": "8:00", "Breakfast": "b", "responsible": "Person1"}, 
        {"time": "18:00", "activity": "Dinner", "responsible": "Person1"}
    ], 
"29-June-2017": 
    [
        {"time": "8:00", "activity": "Breakfast", "responsible": "Person2"}, 
        {"time": "12:00", "activity": "Lunch", "responsible": "Person"}
    ]
}
```

Now, I have solved everything but this so far. I have thought of passing the variable to the template and generate an input where the date can be added for each formset (thus repeating data for every input) and then doing something on the view in order to organize the json file as I want to. Is there a way to make it work? This is my first time working something python so I'm sorry if it looks sloppy:

Views.py:

```
def itinerary(request, id):
    t=get_object_or_404(Team, id = id)
    days = []
    d1 = t.arrival_date
    d2 = t.departure_date
    delta = d2-d1
    for day in range(delta.days+1):
        days.append(d1 + datetime.timedelta(days=day))
    ItineraryFormSet = formset_factory(ItineraryForm, extra=len(days))
    formset = ItineraryFormSet(request.POST or None)
    formset_and_days = zip(formset, days)
    if formset.is_valid():
        clean = formset.cleaned_data
        t.itinerary = json.dumps(clean)
        t.save(update_fields=['itinerary'])
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse ('single', args=[id]))
    return render(request, 'itinerary.html', {'formset': ItineraryFormSet(),
                                              'formset_and_days': formset_and_days,
                                              'team':t, 'days': days})
```

The closest that I've found is this:

```
data = {single_day.strftime("%d-%B-%Y"): formset.cleaned_data for single_day in (d1+datetime.timedelta(n) for n in range(delta.days+1))}
```

However, it doesn't work for my purposes.

Comment: Is this just a matter of displaying the data after they filled in the form? You could use the regroup tag on the template side of things: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup

Comment: That's a good question. I suppose it depends on what works better when I reuse the JSON data. As I build the app, I think of wanting to be able to use this data for other purposes in other apps, so I would think that storing it with the right format is important.